# Cannot log data from JSON-server API with GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql, axios, json-server

I have built an API with JSON-server and I am trying to fetch the data from it using React-Apollo Client.

I'm trying to log the data from API on the console with Query tag, restructure and print the data variable using `console.log()`.

I have no idea why the function is getting print via `console.log()`.

I have the current setup:

- JSON server is running on PORT 4000
- Server is running on PORT 5000
- Client is running on PORT 3000

I am already using CORS tool

Below is my component:

```
const BOOKS_QUERY = gql`
    query BooksQuery {
        books {
            title
            author
            editionYear
        }
    }
`;

<Query query={BOOKS_QUERY}>
  {({ loading, error, data }) => {
     if (loading) return <h4>Loading...</h4>;
     if (error) console.log(error);
     console.log(data);

    return <h1>test</h1>;
  }}
</Query>
```

The content below is code for my schema:

```
const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Book',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLInt },
        title: { type: GraphQLString },
        author: { type: GraphQLString },
        editionYear: { type: GraphQLInt }
    })
});

//Root Query

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        books: {
            type: new GraphQLList(BookType),
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return axios.get('http://localhost:4000/books').then((res) => res.data);
            }
        },
        book: {
            type: BookType,
            args: {
                id: { type: GraphQLInt }
            },
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/books/${args.id}`).then((res) => res.data);
            }
        }
    }
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery
});
```

API:

```
{
    "books": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Java How To Program",
            "author": "Deitel & Deitel",
            "editionYear": "2007"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture",
            "author": "Martin Fowler",
            "editionYear": "2002"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "Head First Design Patterns",
            "author": "Elisabeth Freeman",
            "editionYear": "2004"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "title": "Internet & World Wide Web: How to Program",
            "author": "Deitel & Deitel",
            "editionYear": "2007"
        }
    ]
}
```

I only expect the API data to be logged on console.

Later I will render that data on screen.

Comment: what's your query BOOKS_QUERY? And do you see the API call in the network tab returning results?

Comment: Hi Nazim, thanks for returning. I have updated the component with the BOOK_QUERY

Comment: Answering your last question... Yes, it is returning the results